# CMD file will not run my command in the else block

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a CMD script to execute a Java program. The program requires at least one argument so I created an if else block to check that argument one `%1` is not blank. When I run the script without providing argument one I get the expected `you must provide an argument to run`. But when I do provide the argument the program does not execute. Additionally if I don't have `@echo off` set, the entire script prints out as text in the window when I do provide the proper argument.

**Here's the full script:**

```
    set APP_HOME=C:\Temp\Hammer
    rem Set APP_HOME to the place where you installed Hammer

    if ["%1"] == [""] (

        echo you must provide a python script to run
    ) else (

    java -cp %APP_HOME%\lib\jython.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\hammer.jar;%CLASSPATH% bridenstine.hammer.main.Main %1 %2
    )
```

I think this is a problem with the script and not the program itself because when I run the line that's in the else block by itself without the script,

```
    java -cp C:\Temp\Hammer\lib\jython.jar;C:\Temp\Hammer\lib\hammer.jar;%CLASSPATH% bridenstine.hammer.main.Main argument1
```

The program executes normally. I've been looking at example scripts and cross referencing this site [for CMD files](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) and what I have seems to be valid. Do I have a syntax error?

**Update:**

I'm running the script like so,

```
    cd C:\Temp\Hammer
    bin\ProgramScript.cmd argument1
```

**Update 2:**

Someone pointed out that when they run this script they get an error message saying `Java` is not recognized as an internal or external command (the expected message when Java is not set on their PATH) But they made a good point that this means the script is in fact getting inside the else block. I then pointed out the following,

After I run the script with a valid argument it prints out the entire script as text on the command prompt. I am then able to `mark` the line from inside the else statement (that was printed), copy it, paste it, and it runs the program fine. So the *Java* command seems to be valid. But you make a good point that the script is obviously getting inside the else block...something is still going wrong here and it doesn't seem to be the program.

**Note:**

If relevant I am using Windows 8.1 and I am using the standard command prompt, not one that has administrative privileges (the results remained the same regardless of using a command prompt with administrative privileges).

Comment: When I tried running your script at my computer, with a parameter, I got `'java' is not recognized blah blah ...`. That may well mean that I don't have Java installed but the point is the script did try to execute the `java` line. So, no problem with the script?

Comment: Interesting. You make a good point. However after I run the script with a valid argument it prints out the entire script as text on the command prompt. I am then able to `mark` the line from inside the else statement, copy it, paste it, and it runs the program fine. So the command seems to be valid. But you make a good point that the script is obviously getting inside the else block...something is still going wrong here and it doesn't seem to be the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use

```
set APP_HOME=C:\Temp\Hammer
rem Set APP_HOME to the place where you installed Hammer.

if "%~1"=="" (
   echo You must provide a Python script to run.
   pause
) else (
   java.exe -cp "%APP_HOME%\lib\jython.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\hammer.jar;%CLASSPATH%" bridenstine.hammer.main.Main %*
)
```

It is always better to enclose an argument string in double quotes if it contains environment variables like **CLASSPATH** which might have a string value containing 1 or more spaces.

`%*` is expanded by all arguments passed to the batch file as argument, i.e. %1 %2 ...

It is best to always specify an application like **java** with full path and file extension as otherwise Windows has to search for a file with a file extension as defined in environment variable **PATHEXT** in current working directory and all directories defined in environment variable **PATH**. At least the file extension should be in the batch file if the program files directory of the application varies.

Comment: This is the only solution provided here that worked for me. This answer is very useful and concise.

Answer (score 0):

I can only offer a suggestion; I've not tried this.

I would try escaping each `;` with a caret `^` thus:

```
java -cp %APP_HOME%\lib\jython.jar^;%APP_HOME%\lib\hammer.jar^;%CLASSPATH% bridenstine.hammer.main.Main %1 %2
```

(But I'll admit it's clutching at straws...)

Comment: Sorry this had no effect.

Answer (score -2):

You are missing you she-bang at the top of the script

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: The question is about executing a batch script on windows using cmd, bash doesn't come into it.

Comment: Because your answer is not useful, as it is unequivocally wrong. That is what downvotes are for.

Comment: Having said that, we all make mistakes or misread questions from time to time. Kudos for trying - it's more than the other seven thousand million other out there contributed. (ut you may do well to delete this response yourself)

Comment: Some people will mention a flaw to give you a chance to do something about it.  I'm mentioning that you should delete this answer or other people may downvote your answer too.